# Calling a C method with double pointer parameter from Android with NDK/JNI

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working with an API to control a finger print scanner attached to an android device. The native method I need to call requires a mixture of pointers and double pointers be handed to the method, but I am unsure how to do this.

The original C method has the definition:

```
BioErrType BioGetTemplates(BioHandle handle, char **badgeNumberList,uint8_t *templateIndexList, BioTemplate **bioTemplateList)
```

The provided Java method provided to call this is:

```
public native int BioGetTemplates(int handle, int [] badgeNumberList, byte [] templateIndexList, byte [][]bioTemplateList);
```

The documentation for the original C method states:

```
***    Gets from the biometric device a template for each of the listed
***  badge numbers.
***  
***    The badgeNumberList pointer is a pointer to a null terminated array
***  of pointers to badge number strings.  The bioTemplateList should be an
***  array of pointers to memory where templates can be stored, one pointer
***  for each possible template returned.
***    The templateIndexList is a pointer to an array of template indices.
***  If templateIndexList is not null, than its size must be the same as the
***  number of badge number strings provided via badgeNumberList, which must
***  be the same size as the array of template pointers provided via
***  bioTemplateList. If templateIndexList is null, than the bioTemplateList
***  array size must be a device specific multiple of the number of badge
***  numbers.  For all current devices, this multiple is 2, corresponding to
***  a primary and secondary template for each badge number.
***    Each template is copied from the device to the memory at the
***  corresponding pointer in the bioTemplateList. If no template for a
***  given badge number and template index is stored in the device, the
***  corresponding pointer in the bioTemplateList is set to NULL.  If a
***  template pointer in bioTemplateList is NULL and yet a template exists
***  for the corresponding badge number and index, BIOAPI_INVALID is returned.
***    The applications program shall provide a separate buffer, of a size
***  specific to the device type, for every template it expects.
***
***  returns:
***    BIOAPI_OK if all templates found were copied to the provided template
***  buffers.
***    BIOAPI_INVALID if the handle is invalid or the badgeNumberList pointer
***  is null or if the bioTemplateList pointer is null, or if any badge
***  number in the list is invalid, or if any template index is out of range
***  for the device, or if a null template pointer is provided for a
***  template that is requested and is in the device, or if the device could
***  not successfully be talked to.  This error code can be returned even if
***  some of the templates were copied from the device, if the function was
***  not able to complete.
***    BIOAPI_BUSY if another thread is currently using the library.
```

My current attempt to call the code:

```
            int[] badgeNumberList = { 100, 0 };
            byte[] templateIndexList = new byte[2 * (badgeNumberList.length - 1)];
            byte[][] bioTemplateList = new byte[1][2];

            try {
                mBio.bioGetTemplates(badgeNumberList, templateIndexList,
                        bioTemplateList);

                byte[] byteArr = bioTemplateList[0];
                BigInteger bigTemplate = new BigInteger(byteArr);

                Log.d(TAG, CLASS + "." + METHOD + " BigInt is: "
                        + bigTemplate.toString());

            } catch (BioError e) {
                Log.w(TAG, CLASS + "." + METHOD + ": " + e.getMessage());

            }
```

Note that the mBio object is a façade to the supplied Java API that deals with passing in handle and throws errors based on the integer return of the method.

I realise that I am not doing the correct thing with the output but as of yet I just want to see some output then I can deal with it later.

Currently running this code throws a BIOAPI_INVALID error.

I currently cannot debug on the device itself, only write to the log.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Trying to deal with native pointers from java is non-trivial.  So your best course of action is probably going to be to write native wrappers which exchange Java-compatible buffers/structures with Java, and whatever this native library needs when it calls through to it.  You will need wrappers anyway, as JNI generally imposes many requirements on the naming and signatures of functions it can call.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will get in contact with those who wrote the API and ask them for some additional help. Whilst I do have the source I don't believe I should be the one to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to those who wrote the API, the correct calling is:

```
int[] badgeNumberList = new int[] { 100, 200 };
byte[] templateIndexList = new byte[] { 0, 0 };
byte[][] bioTemplateList = new byte[2][TEMPLATE_SIZE];

mBio.getTemplates(badgeNumberList, templateIndexList, bioTemplateList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

```
BIOAPI_INVALID: ...if any badge number in the list is invalid, ...
```

Might 0 be invalid?

If I were designing the Java API, I would leave out concepts such as "null terminated array" that service only weak C data structures. So, `int [] badgeNumberList` would just be a list of badge numbers.

Try:

```
int[] badgeNumberList = { 100 };
```

You really need the docs for the Java API.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, unfortunately there are no docs for the Java API. I have already tried with just 100 and still get the invalid error. Unfortunately that is a pretty vague error in the doc "x or y or z or... ".

The thing that confuses me about the badge number list is that it should be "a pointer to a null terminated array of pointers to badge number strings.", whereas my array is analogous to whereas mine is just a pointer to an array of ints, right?

Thanks.